# Best way performance wise to check sensor values

Tags: c++, embedded

I am writing some software running on an STM32 chip which controls a small robot. This robot has a few sensors on board that produce data. I use that data to create a JSON at a set interval (in the hundreds of ms) and then I send it to my PC for telemetry purposes. I would like to create a safety event loop that checks at a similar interval that all sensors (10+) read an expected value. I am wondering which would be the most efficient method to retrieve and check these values.

On one hand, I could include all of the sensor classes and then check their values via their own methods which read an analog value (this method is also used by the json generator) or I could include the telemetry generating class and just look at the json it last sent. Of course this will also mean de-serializing to parse for which I use an external library. Which of these two methods would be faster?

Thanks

Comment: Safety and PC are pretty much mutually exclusive. In this also a wireless connection?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that a sensor works as intended by the method the manufacturer devised for the sensor on your embedded device. If the manufacturer did not specify a method you should define some control limits for your sensor and see if the sensor data is in these limits.

To check that the json was correctly transferred to your PC you should use a checksum.